# Purple spots on a common potato plant

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, potatoes, blight

A few months ago, after discarding some store bought purple potatoes that had gone old, I managed to grow some nice potato plants.
Recently, however, I have been noticing purple blotches on the leaves which seems abnormal since with my previous harvests and other reference plants, they don’t seem to have it. The spots have been sparse and only on a few leaves

I haven’t been able to find much on the internet. is it likely early blight? If so, what is to be done?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magnesium-deficiency can look like that on tomatoes. Potatoes are related. I'm not sure if that's the problem, but you never know.